# Как задать расширение файла тега img?

Tags: internet-explorer, html5

Проблема в следующем:
есть сервер, с которого мобильным HTML5 приложением тянутся картинки с расширением .png сжатые как jpeg. То есть, какой-то ленивый человек просто взял и поменял расширение файлов руками с .jpg на .png. Поменять их я не могу.

Как заставить эти картинки отображаться в IE 10+?

Вот пример:
[link text](http://goo.gl/gJIW8v)

Comment: Мне кажется, что нужно написать декодер на `js`. Либо правильные расширения отдавать. У меня на 11ой версии тоже "Не удалось декодировать изображение".

Я бы воспользовался этим декодером: https://github.com/lampaa/imageLib/blob/master/modules/jpeg-decoder.js Дальше бы вставил картинки как canvas элемент. Возможно есть еще какие-то способы.

Comment: Хотя нет, вру, ничего не получится, нету такой штуки в браузерах, как Buffer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        var pic = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: pic.src
        }).done(function(data) {
            pic.src="data:image/jpeg" + data;
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    preload($('img'));

}) ;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><img src="http://komandir.kz/personal/worker/promo/photo/14013427121.png"/></div>

<p>Pic</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Такой вариант прокатит если картинки будут на том же домене, где будет висеть html-страничка. Ну или если ты используешь не браузерный яваскрипт, и имеешь возможность бодренько насрать на crossdomain-restriction.

А, чуть не забыл. Заверни data в base64. Иначе разметка поедет.